# calculate some integral of sum of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two i.i.d. continuous random variables which have probability density function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$ Now I want to calculate the density of $X_1 + X_2$.
$$
f_{X_1+X_2}(z)
 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(z-x_1)dx_1
 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+x_1^2}
                           \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+(z-x_1)^2} dx_1  
$$
Is there any efficient way to calculate this integral?

Comment: Does this integral exist? What happens when $x_1 = z$?

Comment: @RyanGoulden this one does not but the correct one does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake, the correct integral is
$$
\frac{1}{\pi^2} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \frac{1}{1 + (z-x)^2} dx
$$
and I would look around trig substitution or partial fractions...

Comment: thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I think it is not possible to get the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try partial fractions. An integral of (1+(x1)^2)^-1 on its own is fine to work out, it is an arctan integral. Likewise, an integral of (1+(z-x1)^2)^-1 is also very doable.

Comment: Also double check your expression for fx2(z-x1)